# Polymer change selected bar color in tab

Tags: html, css, polymer-1.0, web-component

I tried to change the color of the bottom bar in the tab selected but without success. I can change the background color and the color of the text but not of the bar.. By the way this is what i've done:

```
<paper-tabs selected="0" >

        <paper-tab>TAB1</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>TAB2</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>TAB3</paper-tab>

    </paper-tabs>
    <style shim-shadowdom>

        body.core-narrow {
            padding: 8px;
        }

        paper-tabs, core-toolbar {
            background-color: #00bcd4;
            color: #fff;
            box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        core-toolbar paper-tabs {
            box-shadow: none;
        }

        paper-tabs[noink][nobar] paper-tab.core-selected {
            color: #db352c;
        }

        paper-tabs.transparent-teal {
            background-color: transparent;
            color: #00bcd4;
            box-shadow: none;
        }

        paper-tabs.transparent-teal::shadow #selectionBar {
            background-color: #00bcd4;
        }

        paper-tabs.transparent-teal paper-tab::shadow #ink {
            color: #00bcd4;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 600;
        }

    </style>
```

The color i want is `color: #db352c;` but the bar is still and always yellow!! How can i change it?

Comment: Did you try using the keyword `!important` in your CSS?

Comment: it changes only the color of the text of the tabs! And also it's not what i want!  What i need it's only change the color of the bar. Not the text, not the ripple and not the background. The color of the bar from yellow to what i want.

Comment: The `color` CSS property changes text color. If you want to change the background color of the bar, then you should rather use `background-color: #db352c !important;`

Answer (score 0):

Following this Link: [polymerElements/paper-fab](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-fab/blob/master/demo/index.html)

Example Code:

```
 paper-fab {
        --paper-fab-background: #db352c;
        --paper-fab-keyboard-focus-background: red;
      }
```

Comment: The question is about paper-tabs, not paper-fab.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-tabs) show that there is a custom property to let you change the colour of the selection bar:

```
--paper-tabs-selection-bar-color
```